# Open ball around a set

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading "Topics on Continua" by Sergio Macías, and he provides the following notation on page 2:

"If $\varepsilon$ is a positive real number, then the symbol $\mathcal{V}_{\varepsilon}^d(A)$ denotes the $\textit{open ball of radius } \varepsilon \textit{ about } A$.  "
Here, we are considering a metric space $(X, d)$ and a subset $A$.  The problem is that he doesn't actually define what an open ball of radius $\varepsilon$ about $A$ actually is.  I couldn't find anywhere online how this is defined.  I feel like I should know this by now but honestly I've never seen it in any other classes or text books (or even any papers for that matter).  Does anyone know how such an "open ball" is defined when we are centered about a general set instead of just a point?  Thanks.

Comment: think in term of neighbors that, within the metric $d$, are less than $\varepsilon$ near.

Comment: So it would just be the Union of all such open balls?  That's what I'd figured, but geometrically that doesn't always make a "ball" in the intuitive sense of the word...not that it should matter since this is topology and because there are various types of metrics that don't always make round shapes when centered on points.  I guess I was just a little disturbed by such a notion.

Comment: $B_{\varepsilon}(A)=\bigcup_{p\in A}B_{\varepsilon}(p)$ could be?

Comment: Check uniform neighbourhoods on wikipedia, that’s the standard name of a ball centred at a set.

Comment: Yeah it was a very naive question. I think at the time I was worried that it could mean an open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered on the set's barycentric center so that $\epsilon$ was sufficiently large to contain the entire set. Something silly like that.

Answer (score 1):

It's the set $ \{x \in X \,|\, d(x, A) < \varepsilon\} $, where $d(x, A) = \inf \{d(x, y) \,|\, y \in A\}$.